# J query Error: SyntaxError: missing ; before statement

Tags: javascript

I have some small issue in j query. my code is like this

```
var tt = 8*1;
var n = tt.toString();
var uu1 = n.split('*');

var count = uu1.length;

var table_id44 = '';

for(k = 0,m = 1; k < count-1; k++,m++)
{
var table_id44[m] = uu1[k];
}
```

when I put that i got error in console log SyntaxError: missing ; before statement.please someone help.

Comment: This code will raise a different syntax error (because of `var table_id44[m] = uu1[k];`)

Comment: `var table_id44[m]` is invalid syntax and your loop will never run as `count` is `1`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this, You are declaring it as string `var table_id44 = '';` and using it as an `array`.

```
var tt = "8 * 1";//use it as string so that you can further split it on *
var n = tt.toString();
var uu1 = n.split('*');

var table_id44 = [];

for (k = 0, m = 1; k < count - 1; k++, m++)
{
    table_id44[m] = uu1[k];//prevent multiple declaration in loop
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`table_id44` should be declared as an array. and you don't need to redeclare the variable in the `for` loop.

```
var tt = 8 * 1;
var n = tt.toString();
var uu1 = n.split('*');

var count = uu1.length;

var table_id44 = [];

for (k = 0, m = 1; k < count - 1; k++, m++) {
    table_id44[m] = uu1[k];
}
```